# XMLHttpRequest to elasticsearch with javascript

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch, request

Another site to GET request is work. but, when i request to elasticsearch by localhost is not work.

The status codes are:

Create Object from JSON String
4, 0,

readyState = 4
status = 0

The javascript code for the above result.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h2>
Create Object from JSON String</h2>
<p id="demo">
</p>
<script>

var url = "http://127.0.0.1:9200/";
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = url;
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();


xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xmlhttp.readyState + ", " + xmlhttp.status + ", " + xmlhttp.responseText;
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {

        var response = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myArr;
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

localhost: 9200 isn't work samely
When I search, i read "you can't request by 'localhost' because of browser". but the questioner said "i did that". so i wonder what i have problems...

Comment: add a path to your url, e.g. `http://127.0.0.1:9200/_count?pretty` - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_talking_to_elasticsearch.html

Comment: is not work...all url api is not work on the code...but directly request is work. how to debug this?

Comment: i solved that. i installed that app in chrome . https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi/related

Answer (score 0):

i solved that. i installed that app in chrome
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi/related